# Application.WorkbookBeforeClose event

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel addin which has runs a procedure when closing a workbook.

Is there a way to bypass this procedure using vba code if I want to write another macro that opens a workbook and closes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the macro that is currently running, you can temporarily disable events before closing the other workbook to prevent the WorkbookBeforeClose event (and any other events) from running:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Remember to turn them back on afterwards and also in error handling.